# Json parse error on JSONLint

Tags: javascript, json, parsing, object

I have this JSON output:

```
 {
  "title": "test1",
  "status": "private",
  "markers": "\"[{\"k\":48.28319289548349,\"B\":1.494140625},{\"k\":44.024421519659334,\"B\":20.302734375},{\"k\":47.517200697839414,\"B\":40.517578125},{\"k\":53.9560855309879,\"B\":23.73046875},{\"k\":49.66762782262194,\"B\":3.251953125}]\""
 }

 {
  "title": "test2",
  "status": "public",
  "markers": "\"[{\"k\":48.574789910928864,\"B\":10.546875},{\"k\":43.19716728250127,\"B\":12.48046875}]\""
 }
```

On JSONLint I get this error:

```
 Parse error on line 5:
 ...":3.251953125}]\""}{    "title": "test
 ----------------------^
 Expecting 'EOF', '}', ',', ']'
```

Here is the PHP code witch fetch the JSON objects:

```
 if ($bdd = mysqli_connect('localhost', '', '', _BDD_NAME_)) {
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM `trip`';
    $result = mysqli_query($bdd, $sql);

    if ($result) {
        while  ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo json_encode(array('title'   => stripslashes($row['title']),
                                   'status'  => stripslashes($row['status']),
                                   'markers' => stripslashes($row['markers'])));
        }
    }
    else {
        echo json_encode(array('status' => 'failure'));
    }
}

 if ($bdd) {
    mysqli_close($bdd);
}
```

Can someone help me to identify where is the error in this JSON object?

Comment: This is not valid JSON. It's two JSON objects, not one.

Comment: @HoboSapiens Yes true but I fetch all my JSON object from a MySQL query witch gives me all this output, how can I deal with multiple object?

Comment: @Katcha put them in an array. I feel like this question is really about how you're constructing the JSON response from MySQL. Add your server-side code to the question and we can point out where you're going wrong

Comment: @Phil You're right, you can now see the PHP code.

Comment: I feel like there was a very similar question not long ago. Let me find it

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ajax Call keeps failing without error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27261042/ajax-call-keeps-failing-without-error)

Comment: you are missing a `comma` between `}` and the next opening bracket `{` and wrap everything in square brackets `[]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have more than one object in your JSON here, you must wrap them in an array literal. You also forgot the comma between the JSON objects:

```
[
     {
      "title": "test1",
      "status": "private",
      "markers": "\"[{\"k\":48.28319289548349,\"B\":1.494140625},{\"k\":44.024421519659334,\"B\":20.302734375},{\"k\":47.517200697839414,\"B\":40.517578125},{\"k\":53.9560855309879,\"B\":23.73046875},{\"k\":49.66762782262194,\"B\":3.251953125}]\""
     },
     {
      "title": "test2",
      "status": "public",
      "markers": "\"[{\"k\":48.574789910928864,\"B\":10.546875},{\"k\":43.19716728250127,\"B\":12.48046875}]\""
     }
]
```

Comment: Still the same error even if I had the square bracket, you can check on JSONLint.

Comment: Hmm, JSONLint reports it as valid for me.

Comment: [Katcha](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1106312/katcha) Did you add the comma between the two objects?

Comment: Now yes it's valid, I think it's the edit of @aug! Thank you!

Comment: Yes, this answer points out the problem but it does not address a solution. The JSON is generated server-side

Comment: That's true - I wrote this before they posted their backend code.